# Jquery DataTable invalidate() doesn't work for row that have been added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using the JQuery plugin DataTable, I have a button which allows to the user to add an empty row.
Also, all my cells are editable when you double-click on (I made my own function and I don't use the editor plugin of DataTable because it's not free).

When the user double click on a cell, he can edit the cell, and to save the content, the user has to click out the cell. 
To do that, I call a function when the cell lose the focus that call the `.invalidate()` method of datatable see here ([invalidate function](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell%28%29.invalidate%28%29)) to tell to datatable to refresh the cache with the DOM, so the filter will be able to find the new data added in the table.

But for dynamically added rows that doesn't work, in fact calling the `.invalidate()` function causes an issue, the content of the cell is cleared.

Here my codepen.io : [my code](http://codepen.io/robert91/pen/wWwmeE)

Thank you !

Comment: remove `invalidate()`.. still it works...

Comment: Sorry I wasn't here, yes it works (but the data is not in cache, so the DataTable filter doesn't know there is a new data), that why I use this method. Also this method works with the row which is not added dynamically

Comment: can someone else help me ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?